# From a DNS record, how can one know if the server is a root server?

Tags: dns

Is there a way using DNS to know if a given nameserver is a root server? Looking at the dig output of `dig NS a.root-servers.net`, we can see that its SOA points to itself.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.2 <<>> NS a.root-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19635
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;a.root-servers.net.        IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
root-servers.net.   9684    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019102500 14400 7200 1209600 3600000

;; Query time: 18 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 11 16:03:39 EST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```

For the B root server though, we can see that the SOA still points to `a.root-servers.net`

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
root-servers.net.   86399   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019102500 14400 7200 1209600 3600000
```

The same is also true of 8.8.8.8, which is not a root-server.

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86395   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019111101 1800 900 604800 86400
```

Is there some way within the record we can know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression that you are going about this in a sort of backwards way. The nameservers for a zone (including but not limited to the root zone) are specified by `NS` records at the zone apex, there is nothing about the name of a nameserver that specifies which zones it will answer authoritatively for.

Ie, you can get the list of root servers by:

```
dig . NS
```

From a different perspective, if you want to test if a given server behaves like a root server (answers authoritatively for the root zone), you could do something like this:

```
dig @serveryouwanttotest . SOA
```

and check the *flags* (in the header, not a record) of the response for the `aa` (authoritative answer) flag.

Example:

```
dig @a.root-servers.net . SOA
```

yields `flags: qr aa rd` (`aa` present)

vs

```
dig @8.8.8.8 . SOA
```

yields `flags: qr rd ra ad` (no `aa` present)

Comment: Yep! The intent was to work backwards through the chain. Thank you!